# Same height li and auto adjust container div's height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have horizontally aligned li elements all with same height with some minimum height. I want the size of the container div to increase from some minimum height with increase in height of li elements. Here is the jsfiddle of what I have tried: http://jsfiddle.net/6NKn2/a

HTML:

```
<div id='d'>
<ul id='u'>
    <li class='l'>item 1 long item long item long long long long long long</li>
    <li class='l'>item 2</li>
    <li class='l'>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#d {
    min-height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#u {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid green;
    height: 100%;
}
.l {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I can't figure out how to achieve this. Also I would like to avoid new CSS3 properties to support old IE (7+). Use of JavaScript is also fine. Can you please help me with this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to have all `<li>` elements in same height use this JQuery code:

```
var $height = 0 ;
$("li.l").each(function(){
    if(($(this).height())>$height){
            $height = $(this).height();
    }
});
$("li.l").each(function(){
    $(this).css("height",$height)
});
```

for increase height of container you need to set `overflow:auto` :

```
#d
{
    min-height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow:auto;   /*  added  */
}
```

[**here is jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6NKn2/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Cross-Browser Min Height

The CSS min-height is one of the most requested css snippets to solve the annoying min-height problems in IE.

Example IE

```
#d  {
       min-height: 500px;
       height:auto !important;
       height: 500px;
       overflow:auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow:auto;`

**For Instance,**

```
#d {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    min-height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6NKn2/3/)**

Comment: now div height is expanding fine, but what about li height, I want all li height to be same.

Comment: You can make any `height` changes to your `li`, as `overflow:auto;` will make it expand accordingly. - @Harshveer

Answer (score 0):

```
#d
{
    min-height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    min-height: 500px;
    height:auto !important;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about adding `overflow: auto` to `#d` rule?

Answer (score 0):

```
#d
{
    min-height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float:left;
}
```

> use this code for id `#d`

Answer (score 0):

Remove min-height in #d and place the css property

```
float:left
```

[Fiddle DEMO :](http://jsfiddle.net/syedazam/6NKn2/7/)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by applying height of **ul** to all **li** by jQuery

on loading the page first get the height of **ul** which is equal to height of li which has largest height and apply same height to inner **li**

[Here is the demo for it](http://codepen.io/tusharbandal/pen/LpIBK)

Answer (score 0):

First you need the mentioned min-height for container #d

```
#d  {
   min-height: 500px;
   height:auto !important;
   height: 500px;
   overflow:auto;
}
```

Aditionally you need to add a clearfix of the left floating list elements in order to expand the surrounding container when the list grwos in height:

```
<div id='d'>
  <ul id='u'>
    <li class='l'>item 1 long item long item long long long long long long</li>
    <li class='l'>item 2</li>
    <li class='l'>item 3</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="clearleft"></div>
</div>


.clearleft {
  clear: left;
}
```

Here the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PAh7u/1/)